# pregunta sobre ajax mostrar resultados individuales

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Quiero mostrar el resultado de una consulta AJAX en diferentes partes de mi sitio web. Es decir en mi consulta tengo dos `echo` dentro del PHP que quiero imprimir en mi documento HTML.

El problema es que me los muestra los dos juntos. Por ejemplo:

```
NOMBRE:   //aqui que me muestre el nombre de mi variable nombre en php
EDAD:     //aqui que me muestre la edad de mi variable edad en php
```

pero a la hora de hacer la consulta me arroja el siguiente ejemplo:

```
NOMBRE:andy 18 //nombre y edad juntos
EDAD:andy 18 //nombre y edad juntos
```

Aquí un ejemplo del código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
  $(".info").click(function(e){
    var nombre=$("#nombre").val();
    var edad=$("#edad").val();

    $("#formulario").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        url:"info.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:${nombre:nombre,edad:edad},
        beforesend:function(){
          $("#resultados").html("<img src='img/loading.gif'>");
        },
        success:function(data){
          $("#resultados1").html(data); //aqui un div para mostrar el nombre
          $("#resultados2").html(data);//aqui un div para mostrar la edad
        }
      });
    });
  }); 
});
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php
  //esto viene de dos input
  $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
  $edad=$_POST['edad'];

  echo $nombre;
  echo $edad;

?>
```

Comment: Hola @andy, bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías publicar el código que intentaste hasta ahora? Es mucho más sencillo responder, y encontrarás más chances de que alguien se interese si ya hay una base sobre la cual enfocarse en algo concreto. Encontrarás el enlace a **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. La idea es que todas las preguntas tengan un [mcve]. Además, siempre etiquetá tu pregunta con el lenguaje de programación esperado en las respuestas... Asumo que es [tag:javascript] en este caso... Y, al pegar tu código, seleccionalo completamente y presioná el botón `{  }` para darle formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento con este ejemplo como deberías de realizarlo:

En este HTML yo ingreso 2 valores los cuales quiero mostrar en 2 div por separado

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" id="datos">
    <input type="text" name="valor1"  />
    <input type="text" name="valor2" />
    <input type="button" id="muestra_datos" value="Muestrame" />
</form>

<div id="resultado"></div><!--aquí se va a mostrar mi primer valor-->
<div id="resultado1"></div></div><!--aquí se va a mostrar mi segundo valor-->

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="funciones.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

En el archivo PHP que los procesa, meto los valores dentro de un array asociativo a los cuales asocio con una clave en forma de texto que usaré para recuperarlos después

```
<?php   
$numero1 = $_POST['valor1'];
$numero2 = $_POST['valor2'];

header("Content-Type: application/json");

echo json_encode(array("valor1" => $valor1, "valor2" => $valor2));
```

Finalmente en mi archivo AJAX accedo con el objeto data al valor individual que deseo mostrar por medio de la clave que mas arriba mencioné mira

```
$(function(){
  $('#muestra_datos').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'datos.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#datos').serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        $('#resultado').html(data['valor1'])
        $('#resultado1').html(data['valor2'])
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: hey man totalmente funcional mil gracias me funciono de maravillas

Comment: ya lo hice gracias man

Comment: si tienes otra duda, ya sabes puedes postearla

Comment: gracias eres genial man

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas que el nombre quede separado de la edad puedes agregar un BR luego de imprimir el nombre

```
echo $nombre;
echo '<br />';
echo $edad;
```

De lo contrario como estás imprimiendo en 2 divs diferentes con css puedes hacer que uno este debajo del otro, pero esto sería otro tema.

Comment: si te entiiendo pero ese no es mi problema, yo quiero que eso dos escho me aparescan en la posision que yo deseo por ejemplo que yo tenga el nombre en el header y la edad en el footer ,yo quiero que el echo de el nombre aparesca en el header y el echo de la edad en el footer me doy a entender?

Comment: la respuesta que otorga PHP a JS la interpreta este último como una sola

Comment: si entonces como hago para hacer lo que quiero  ayuda porfis

Comment: te deje mi respuesta si gustas revisarla

Comment: Ah ok, en ese caso lo que debes hacer en realidad es que el php te devuelva un json por lo que los valores a devolver los debes de guardar en un array para luego hacerle echo json_encode(); mira aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php